# Sending the Space key in Autokey

Tags: autokey

I'm trying to make an autokey script to send the date when I press the assigned hotkey. In the end Im hoping for it to look something like "September 20th, 2022". So far what I have is, `system.exec_command("date +%B-%d-%Y")` which sends the date but it adds the little "-" instead of a space. I know it's because I have that in the code but I can't find what the correct way to make it send the space key is. I know for sending the return/enter key it's `"<enter>"` so I tried doing it like `"<space>"` but it didn't work. Does anyone know what the correct way to type it is? also if you do could you direct me to somewhere where i could find a list of those kind of "commands" so to speak for future endeavors. thanks

Also i don't think there's a way to do it after looking at the bottom of this [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) but if anyone knows how to get the correct suffix like the "th" and "st" in 20th and 21st that would be helpful too thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

"Escape" the spaces, as in `date +%B\ %d\ %Y`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @vanadium s specific solution, you can save the result of your function (`system.exec_command()` or anything else) in a string variable and use all of Python including the strings module functions, to manipulate that string in any desired way before emitting it from your script. You can use `subprocess.check()` instead if you have issues getting the results into a string to start with.